# Google Map markers not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to implement markers on my static webpage using Javascript, KnockoutJS and google maps API. The page loads up the initMaps() function but when I try to load the markers they are not showing up. Please help me, I am using MVVM for the first time and let me know where I am wrong.

map.html goes here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html,
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="/Users/jainamshah/Desktop/Nhmap/app.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout.js'></script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#KEPTPRIVATE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var locations = [
      {title: 'by CHLOE', 
      location: {lat: 42.351114, lng: -71.045021}
  },
      {title: 'Tamazcal', 
      location: {lat: 42.348904, lng: -71.038292}
  },
      {title: 'Boston Kashmir', 
      location: {lat: 42.349317, lng: -71.083926}
  },
      {title: 'Max Brenner', 
      location: {lat: 42.349348, lng: -71.080829}
  },
      {title: 'Thai Basil', 
      location: {lat: 42.350925, lng: -71.076643}
  },
      {title: 'Boston Burger CO`', 
      location: {lat: 42.34681, lng: -71.088473}
  }
    ];
var map;

var markers = [];
function initMap() {
    // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 42.360083, lng: -71.05888},
      zoom: 13
    });

    bindItAll();
  }





var Model = function(data){

  this.title = data.title;
  this.location = data.location;


  this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: this.title,
    position: this.location,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

 });
  var largeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  this.marker.addListener('click', function() {
        populateInfoWindow(this, largeInfowindow);
      });

function populateInfoWindow(marker, infowindow) {

    if (infowindow.marker != marker) {
      infowindow.marker = marker;
      infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div>');
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      // Make sure the marker property is cleared if the infowindow is closed.
      infowindow.addListener('closeclick',function(){
        infowindow.setMarker = null;
      });
    }
  }
}

var ViewModel = function(){

  var self = this;
  this.Locations = ko.observableArray();

  locations.forEach(function(data){
  self.Locations.push( new Model(data) );
 });
  }

function bindItAll() {
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers must be attached to the map, which is missing in your code.

This can be done when instantiating a `Marker` via the property `map`.

```
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: this.title,
    position: this.location,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map
});
```

or later via the method `setMap`.

```
this.marker.setMap(map);
```